# Allowing <img> tags in Content-type: application/msword

Tags: php, image, ms-word, content-type

Right now, I have everything fine. It prints according to my CSS (text-align: center;).
the only problem I have is with the image. This is the HTML code:

```
<table id="cert">  
    <td>  
        <tr><h1>Singapore Aviation Academy</h1></tr>  
        <tr><img src = "img/logo1.jpg" /></tr>  
        <tr><h2>Certificate of Completion </h2></tr>  
        <tr>is hereby granted to</tr>  
        <tr><?php echo "<b>".$row['fname']."&nbsp;&nbsp;".$row['lname']."</b>"; ?> </tr>  
        <tr>to certify that he/she has completed to satisfaction for</tr>  
        <tr><?php echo "<b>".$row1['course_title']."</b>"; ?></tr>  
    </td>  
</table>
```

Right after that:

```
<?php       
//This php will enable documents to be embedded with Microsoft Word

header("Content-type: application/msword"); //Document will be embedded using the application, Microsoft Word  
header("Content-disposition: attachment; filename= \"Certificate for ".$row['fname']." ".$row['lname']."\""); //States the file name when opened to edit or view  
?>
```

The problem is in that `<img>` tag. Without the last lines of PHP codes, the image appears. With it, the image just won't show in the MS-Word.

Any idea how to solve this?

Comment: I cringe every time I see somebody trying to pass HTML markup off as an MS Office document simply be changing the headers

Comment: What does an `<img>` tag have to do with MS Word?

Comment: @Mark Baker: It's the first tie I see it, but a piece of my soul died already...

Comment: Every time someone passes off HTML as MS Office data, this happens to a kitten: http://www.startrek.com/legacy_media/images/200506/ds9-437-arjin002/320x240.jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The image won't appear when opened in Word because word is running on the client's desktop and looking for the image locally... unless you specify a full URL for the image file, it doesn't know to look on your server.

Options:

- Modify your HTML so the image binary is embedded rather than a link
- Use the full URL for your image
- Create a "real" word document, with the image correctly embedded rather than as a link
- Create a PDF with the image embedded rather than linked, or linked using the full URL

Comment: I'm not even sure how to create a full PDF. I keep getting errors.

Comment: For something like a certificate that tells the world that the holder is eligible and safe to fly aircraft, I'd recommend a PDF (which takes more effort to edit) rather than a document than anybody in the world can edit to show their own name.

Comment: Is there any link you could give for me to look through to this? I've tried a few things, bt nothing seems to work.

Comment: http://www.devarticles.com/c/a/PHP/Use-PHP-to-Create-Dynamic-pdf-Files/ First article I came to having googled on create pdf with php... if you get errors trying to create a PDF, ask for help with the specifics here on SO

Comment: @Syed Abdul Rahman: To create PDFs in PHP, I recommend [wkhtmltopdf](http://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/) if you are able to execute programs, otherwise [dompdf](http://code.google.com/p/dompdf/).